# If $X$ is a discrete random variable and $E(\min(X,M))= E(X)$, prove $P(X>M)=0$

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable, and $E(\min(X,M))= E(X)$. Prove $P(X>M)=0$.

When I took the first look of this question I thought this was very intuitive, but the only thing I really come up with is that $X$ always $< M$ since $\min(X,M)=X$. But how to write a real proof for that?

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: You are incorrectly assuming that $\min(X,M)=X$. The statement
$$E(\min(X,M))=E(X)$$
does not imply that
$$\min(X,M)=X.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $X-\min\{X,M\}$ is a non-negative random variable with expectation $0$.

Comment: so $E(X-min(X,M))$ = 0 is what you are saying? sorry i still don't have clues here

Comment: Yes, by linearity of expectation.